# Children's book about an island that sinks beneath the ocean

Tags: identification-request

There is a children's book published in the early 1980s which was about a pair of islands. On one island the people were rich and valued money above all else, and on the other island the people were not.

The island with the rich people began to sink beneath the ocean as a result.
The cover had a beautiful illustration of the two islands with a third sunken island clearly visible in the illustration presumably indicating that it had happened before.

My memory is of a hardback book perhaps 3mm thick and about 1ft square in size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Sea People](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805238131) by Jörg Müller and Jörg Steiner

[image: cover]

> The superiority of the differing ways of life on two neighboring
>   islands is put to the test when gold is discovered on one of them.

From the reviews on amazon:

> "The Sea People is a simple story about two islands. One is peopled by
>   a proud, disciplined, organised people, the other by an easygoing,
>   slow-paced, fun-loving people. Driven by their king's greed, the proud
>   people eventually bring both people - and both islands - to the edge
>   of ruin."
>
> "It vividly details the changing circumstances of 'the Sea People' as
>   they trade their traditional values for material success and
>   security."